# Pasleyjs Change default behavior of button in parsley form validation

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am using parsleyjs for form validation. I have two buttons 'save' and 'cancel'. I want to use save button for submitting the form, and for cancel button I do not want to submit form. Currently when I click any of them, they take me to form submission

```
<form id="form_validation">
   <div>
      <input type="text" required/>
   </div>
   <div>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
      <button type="submit">Cancel</button>
   </div>
</form>

<script>
            var $formValidate = $('#form_validation');
            $formValidate.parsley().on('form:submit', function () {
                 //this code is called when I click save or cancel button
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you 'cancel' button isn't to submit the form, then it shouldn't have a `type="submit"`. Problem solved.

Comment: then what button type should I use ?